# Accessing GitLab server login hosted on AWS EC2 using an SSH tunnel

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, ssh, gitlab, ssh-tunnel

For a GitLab server that is hosted on an AWS EC2 instance. I would like to view the GitLab server login page via a SSH tunnel similar to that which is done [here](http://toreopsahl.com/2011/10/17/securely-using-r-and-rstudio-on-amazons-ec2/) for R-studio, where in the blog it says that by typing `http://localhost:8787` on the local machine web-browser you are able to access R-studio server. Another example would be [this](http://howto.ccs.neu.edu/howto/windows/ssh-port-tunneling-with-putty/). But for my purposes, I would hope that when using a local machine web-browser with the address bar saying something like...'http://localhost:8082' but this leading me to the GitLab server login. The reason for doing this is to ensure security by only having port 22 open for SSH only which is used for both PuTTy login but also for the tunnel.

Here is what I have done so far:

I have launched a t2.micro instance with Ubunutu 14.04 and downloaded and installed GitLab CE Omnibus as per [this page](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/)

I think i need to alter to the external url in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rd to something like:

`external_url 'http://ip-xxx-xx-x-x.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8082'`

After running PuTTy to SSH into the EC2 instance, and having set a tunnel so that the source port is `8082` and the destination is `localhost:8082` and clicking `Add`.

I would expect to be able to go to my web-browser and in the address bar run `http://localhost:8082` for the login page for GitLabs to turn up... but unfortunately this does not happen at the moment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Choosing port 5555 seemed to work...not too sure why...